# How to get the gameobject- which triggered the UI.Button click function

Tags: unity-game-engine

in Unity 5- I am trying to **disable a ui.button- once it is clicked**. There is a list of buttons- among which- the clicked one will be disabled. But I am not sure, if it is possible to get the event triggering gameobject.

Unity Editor-

[image]

Code:

```
    // called from ui.button clicks
    public void callThisMethod(string param) {

        // how to get the clicked button gameobject here 

    }
```

Comment: Where is your script attached? is in a different game object?

Comment: @RobertoGuajardo Nope. Its attached to Main Camera. So, Debug.Log(gameObject.name)  will show- "Main Cemera"; not the Button name. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this to your code:

```
   public Button yourButton;

   public void yourButtonClicked(){
         yourButton.interactable = false;
    }
```

Assign your button to the Button object in inspector. Then where it says "On Click()" in the image you have above, select the script the above code is added to, and select the "yourButtonClicked()" function. That will disable the button once it is clicked.

To get your clicked button game object, you can use: EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject

Comment: In this case I think he only needs to use EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject... instead of assigning the button in the inspector ... what about something like
GameObject obj = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject;
if(obj.GetComponent<Button>() != null) {obj.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false}

Comment: @Lesile Lu +1, Thank you.  Yes, that's exactly what I was needed- EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.

Answer (score 2):

Just Add another event to return the button

[image]

```
public Button ButtonPressed(Button ThisButton)
{
     return ThisButton;
}
```

Comment: Gave this a +1 because it did answer the question for me with a small modification. In my event handler: public void ButtonActionPress(PressableButtonHoloLens2 thisButton ) then in the Inspector you drag the button into the parameter. This passes the button to the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `gameObject` of the button as a parameter while your are adding event listener to the UI button.
Hope that helps:

```
GameObject myButtonGameObject = myButton.gameObject;

myButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {LogName(myButtonGameObject); });

public void LogName(GameObject buttonGameObject = null){
    Debug.Log(myButtonGameObject);
}
```

**Note**: The given approach is useful, when you need to dynamically show the clicked buttons name, but if you know the exact button, you can make a public field for the `myButton` and get the name without passing any parameters.